# An happy coincidence for the approximate solution of $x \tan(x)=k $?

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, transcendental-equations

Thinking more about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917780/solving-for-lambda-in-frack-lambda-alpha-tan-lambda-r-1-0/2918609#2918609) where I proposed some approximate solution of the first positive root of equation $\color{blue}{x\tan(x)=k}$ for any $k >0$, I notice that, for the $[3,4]$ Padé approximant built at $x=0$
$$\tan(x)=\frac{5 x \left(21-2 x^2\right)}{105-45 x^2+x^4} $$ the denominator  cancels at
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(45-\sqrt{1605}\right)}\approx 1.57123\qquad x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(45+\sqrt{1605}\right)}\approx 6.52160$$ that is to say close to $\frac \pi 2$ (which seems "normal") and "rather close" to $2\pi$ (more surprising). This is the only case for all explored $[2n-1,2n]$  Padé approximants.

This gave me the idea of working the series expansion 
$$(2\pi-x)(2\pi+x)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right) \left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right) x\tan (x)=\pi ^4 x^2+\left(\frac{\pi ^4}{3}-\frac{17 \pi ^2}{4}\right) x^4+O\left(x^6\right)\tag 1$$  reducing the original problem to 
$$\frac{\pi^2 x^2\left(\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-\frac{17}{4}\right) x^2 +\pi^2\right) }{x^4-\frac{17 \pi ^2 }{4}x^2+\pi ^4 }=k$$ which is just a quadratic equation in $x^2$ the retained solution of which being
$$x= \pi\sqrt{\frac{51 k+12 \pi
   ^2-\sqrt{2025 k^2+\pi ^2 \left(192 \pi ^2-1224\right) k+144 \pi ^4}}{2 \left(12 k+\pi ^2 \left(51-4 \pi ^2\right)\right)}}$$ which seems to lead to quite good approximations (in the table below $k=10^n$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 -3 & 0.03161750711 &  0.03161750711 \\
 -2 & 0.09983363885 &  0.09983363855 \\
 -1 & 0.31105293142 &  0.31105284820 \\
  0 & 0.86034131667 &  0.86033358902 \\
  1 & 1.42887264708 &  1.42887001121 \\
  2 & 1.55524418982 &  1.55524512931 \\
  3 & 1.56922698357 &  1.56922710099 \\
  4 & 1.57063925088 &  1.57063926287
\end{array}
\right)$$ For large values of $k$, the asymptotics is
$$x=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{ \pi ^3(4 \pi ^2-3)}{720\,k}+\frac{\pi ^5 \left(4 \pi ^2-3\right)
   \left(436 \pi ^2-3207\right)}{7776000\,
   k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ where we can notice that each coefficient is again very close to $\pm\frac \pi 2$

> Is there a way to justify the appearance of this value close to $\pm 2\pi$ or is it just an happy coincidence ?

By the way, it is possible to improve the coefficients appearing in $(1)$ minimizing
$$\Phi(a,b)=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\left((2\pi-x)(2\pi+x)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right) \left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right) x\tan (x)-(ax^2+bx^4) \right)^2\,dx$$ and get analytical formulae for $a,b$ in terms of $\zeta (p)$ $(p=3,5,7,9)$ and powers of $\pi$. Compared to the initial values, the value of $\Phi(a,b)$ is reduced by a factor of $2.22$.  The expressions for the optimal $a,b$ are not given here but they are available to any one who would like to get them.

**Edit**

About he "coincidence", consider the $[4,2]$ Padé approximant 
$$\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right) \left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right) x\tan (x)=\frac{\frac{\pi ^2}{4}x^2+\frac{\left(720-60 \pi ^2-\pi ^4\right) }{60 \left(\pi
   ^2-12\right)}x^4 } {1-\frac{2 \left(\pi ^2-10\right) }{5 \left(\pi ^2-12\right)}x^2 }$$ and the roots of the denominator are $\pm\sqrt{\frac{60-5 \pi ^2}{20-2 \pi ^2}}\approx \pm 6.39100$.

Comment: A great approximation, especially considering the agreement with the exact values for such a large range of parameters. No idea why this works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Phi(a,b)=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\Big[(2\pi-x)(2\pi+x)\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right) \left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right) x\tan (x)-(ax^2+bx^4) \Big]^2\,dx$$ is minimal for
$$a=-\frac{35}{4 \pi ^6}\Big[371 \pi ^6 \zeta (3)-18906 \pi ^4 \zeta (5)+65520 \pi ^2 \zeta (7)+816480  \zeta (9) \Big]$$
$$b=\frac{63}{ \pi ^8}\Big[311 \pi ^6 \zeta (3)-14838 \pi ^4 \zeta (5)+50400 \pi ^2 \zeta (7)+635040
   \zeta (9) \Big]$$ and, numerically, $\Phi_{\text{opt}}(a,b)=9.182\times 10^{-6}$.

Answer (score 0):

*Five years later.*

I suppose that this could be related to the "new" sharp bounds given by Bagul and Chesneau in year $2019$.

For any $x \in \left(0,\frac \pi 2\right)$
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{128}{\pi^4} \frac{\left(5 \pi ^2-12 x^2\right) x^2}{ \left(\pi
   ^2-4 x^2\right)^2}} < \frac{\tan(x)}x <\sqrt{1+\frac{2\pi^2} {15}\frac{\left(5 \pi ^2-12 x^2\right) x^2}{ \left(\pi
   ^2-4 x^2\right)^2}}$$

Using
$$\tan(x) \sim x \sqrt{1+a\,\frac{\left(5 \pi ^2-12 x^2\right) x^2}{ \left(\pi
   ^2-4 x^2\right)^2}}$$ this leads to solving a cubic equation in $t=x^2$
$$4 (4-3 a)\,t^3+\left(\pi ^2 (5 a-8)-16 k^2\right)\,t^2+\pi^2\left(8  k^2+\pi ^2\right)\,t-k ^2 \pi ^4 =0$$