# Identity of tan(x)

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

I came across the following formulas for analytical expressions of fundamental modes of asymmetric dielectric waveguide. $$ \tan(x) = x\frac{\pi^2-x^2}{\pi^2-4x^2} $$
This approximation is not present in Abramowitz's handbook. It has the same poles and zeros as $\tan(x)$.

Can someone guide me on its merits or where to find it. This doesn't seem like an identity to me.

Comment: No, it has only finitely many poles and zeroes, while $\tan$ has infinitely many.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the range  of [-pi,pi]

Comment: @Somos The "=" sign should be an approximation sign

Comment: @imranfat Yes, I know. But likely the "=" comes from the source. It is obvious it can't be an identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to think about approximating $\tan x$ as a rational function.

Taking the log-derivative of $\sin x=x\prod_{k\ge 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)$ gives $$\cot x=\frac{1}{x}-2\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{x}{k^2\pi^2-x^2}.$$Keeping only the $k=1$ term,$$\tan x\approx\frac{x(\pi^2-x^2)}{\pi^2-3x^2}.$$This is a reasonable approximation if $|x|\ll\pi$, so the right-hand side approximates$$x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{3x^2}{\pi^2}\right)\approx x+\frac{2}{\pi^2}x^3.$$However, the $3\mapsto 4$ replacement changes the $x^3$ coefficient to $\frac{3}{\pi^2}$, a much closer approximation of the exact result $\frac13$ (the Taylor series of $\tan x$ of course continues past the $x^3$ term).

A simpler motive for $\frac{\tan x}{x}\approx\frac{\pi^2-x^2}{\pi^2-4x^2}$ is that the right-hand side is an odd function and approximates $1$ for small $x$, diverges at $x=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ and vanishes at $x=\pm\pi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. Can you guide me towards a resource (book) to read on such approximations ? Could also please tell me about the definition of sine you used ?

Comment: @SSB I don't know of a book on rational approximations for functions, but for the form I gave of $\sin x$ see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Examples_of_factorization).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an identity, but just an approximation for $\tan$.

If you look at their graphs, you'll notice that the two functions line up very, very well though for $|x|\leq\pi$.

[image]

Comment: Yes,  I came up with a similar conclusion. However, I couldn't find this approximation anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, this is an approximation.

In this domain, quite a lot of things can be done. Concerning the tangent, if you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941677/an-happy-coincidence-for-the-approximate-solution-of-x-tanx-k), you will see another one
$$\tan(x) \sim x\frac{\pi^2 \left(\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-\frac{17}{4}\right) x^2 +\pi^2\right) }{\left(x^2-4 \pi ^2\right) \left(x^2-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right)}$$ and notice that $\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-\frac{17}{4}$ is almost $-1$